# Open location.href only one time when it is clicked on pagination

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the pagination option which is loading from template file on each page. I have implemented to open a pop-up window once clicked to open a pop up:

```
<a onClick="location.href='http://google.com/';" target="_blank"" href="http://www.yahoo.com"</a>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to restrict this to be working only one time? To open only one time this window? So when a user is browsing the rest of the pages, I don't want it to work.

The way I see is is I have to create a user cookie or session where to log if he have clicked it or not. I was wandering if there is a simplier way to do it.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expect to open? google or yahoo?

Comment: Do you mean they can only ever open that window once, even if they close it? Or that they can only have one of those windows open at a time? More importantly, what research have you done to try and solve this on your own?

Comment: Open both windows, if I click second page of the pagination, after if I click again on 3th or any other to open only the href=""  it is not important if the opened already pop-up window is there or not.

Comment: Are you tried non `_blank` target? Like `target="myPopup"`.

Comment: @JohnSiniger I'm sorry. Your last comment made almost no sense.

Comment: Or `onclick="this.onclick=''; location.href='http://example.org/'"`

Comment: It is a simple scenario: I go to the page click on this link, it opens popup which is google, and opens also the same page. When I click again on this link on the same page the pop-up should not be working anymore. by a pop-up I am calling the onClick="" event.

Comment: `also the same page` - I miss that in your code, where are you do it?

Comment: same page is yahoo.com as example.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can do it like this:

```js
$(".do-it-once").on("click",function openLink(){
    console.log('navigate')
    $(this).off("click",openLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="do-it-once">Only Once</a>
```

But this will work everytime the page loads. So I suggest opening google in blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot think of anything better than this--at least with sticking to JavaScript vanilla

```js
(function(){
  
  
  document.getElementById('one-click').addEventListener("click", fn);
  
  function fn(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('First click');
    this.removeEventListener(event.type, fn);
  };
  
})();
```

```html
<a id="one-click" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
```